# How to find the maximum value of the column in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public Cursor getBiggestInTheColumn() 
{
     return db.query(HEADER_TABLE, null,"MAX(key_Division)", null, null, null, null);
}
```

and I call this method as  `Cursor cc=db.getBiggestInTheColumn();`

But it forcefully close the application.Please help me

Comment: Could you please put some log here?

Answer (score 25):

You can use `simpleQueryForLong` and cast it accordingly.

```
public int getMaxColumnData() {

    mDb = mDbManager.getReadableDatabase();
    final SQLiteStatement stmt = mDb
            .compileStatement("SELECT MAX(column) FROM Table");

    return (int) stmt.simpleQueryForLong();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public int getBiggestInTheColumn() 
{
    Cursor c = db.query(HEADER_TABLE, null,new String[] {"MAX(key_Division)"}, null, null, null, null); 
    try {
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c.getInt(0);
    } finally {
        c.close();
    }
}
```